# Eclipse Jetty Feature integrate Jetty 9

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jetty

I want to integrate Jetty with Eclipse. And I have installed "Eclipse Jetty Feature(3.6)" in my Eclipse.

I want to configure Eclipse jetty feature. eclipse_debug configurations_jetty webapp_options, I include my own jetty 9 (c:\****\jetty-9.0), but I get an alert when I start to run it:

```
Failed to resolve Jetty dependencies: [.*/com.sun.el-.*\.jar, .*/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-.*\.jar, .*/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-.*\.jar]
```

Can anyone help me to resolve it? I don't have any idea. Thank you. I already added el-api.jar, jsp-api.jar, sevlet-api.jar into my classpath.

Comment: Check if you have this problem: https://github.com/eclipse-jetty/eclipse-jetty-plugin/issues/6

Answer (score 2):

Move

{jetty-9-dir}/lib/apache-jsp

to

{jetty-9-dir}/lib/jsp

Should fix the issue without having to disable JSP.

As far as I can tell Jetty 9.3+ does not include JSTL so you may also have to add that as a dependency if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Disable JSP Support in Debug Config --> Options tab.
But after that, you can't play with jsp anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.9.0 of eclipse-jetty released yesterday (2015-10/11) solves that problem:

http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/changes-report.html#a3.9.0

https://github.com/eclipse-jetty/eclipse-jetty-plugin/issues/15